# How do I set up a non-authoritative name server with Microsoft DNS Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

Is there a guide on how to set up windows server 2008 DNS server as a non-authoritative name server? IN other words a server that has no zones, and computers in the network use it as their DNS server to resolve domains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just installing the Server 2008 DNS role sets it up as a Caching DNS server out of the box. You have to take actions to make it authoritative. It's as simple as just installing the DNS Role in Server Manager and then pointing your clients at it.